# "Turn" printing using PrinterSettings using C#

Tags: c#, printing, telerik-reporting

I'm trying to print labels with a dynamic content. The print works fine but the problem is that the printing itself (the font) is 90 degrees twisted. It looks like this:

[image: twisted]

But it should look like this:

[image: correct]

I cannot change the settings of the printer because other labels do print correct. So I think it must be something in the code. You can watch the C# code here:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();

printerSettings.PrinterName = @"\\server\printer";
printerSettings.Copies = Convert.ToInt16((Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["Counter"].Value.ToString()) - 1));

System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController standardPrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();

Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
reportProcessor.PrintController = standardPrintController;
Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = myReport;
reportProcessor.PrintReport(instanceReportSource, printerSettings);
```

Does anyone know such a problem or a possible solution?

Suggestion very appreciated :)

Comment: What is *"etiquettes"*?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I chose the wrong translation :) I mean label

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library? You should mention that in your question. It's important to know how the printing is being performed, which is likely the code in `PrintReport` function

Comment: I edited the code in my question. I'm using `Telerik` for `reportProcessor.PrintReport()` method

Comment: OK, I have added the appropriate tag for you. I do not have enough experience with the library to help any further but hopefully someone will come along that does

Comment: Sounds like [this kind of problem](http://www.telerik.com/forums/label-prints-in-wrong-orientation-when-the-paper-width-is-greater-than-height).  Do use the vendor's site to find help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem once, but never used Telerik for anything. I was trying to print a XPS file with the PrintServer object, and came up with this solution to rotate the print.

Basicly I change the page orientation of the queue before I print for the user, and then change it back afterwards.

It might be usefull to you as well.

```
PrintServer ps = new PrintServer("\\\\somePrintServer");
var queue = ps.GetPrintQueue("printerShareName");
var oldOrientation = queue.UserPrintTicket.PageOrientation;
queue.UserPrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
//print job here
queue.UserPrintTicket.PageOrientation = oldOrientation;
```